# Send single json object string with message payload at a time with Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-integration, activemq-classic

I'm using spring integration to poll a database using a JdbcPollingChannelAdapter and then post the results onto an Activemq queue using JmsSendingMessageHandler. I'm serializing the jdbc results as json string using a MappingJackson2MessageConverter. When the message get's sent, it gets sent as an arraylist. Is it possible to only send a single json-serialized object with the payload of a message at a time? This would allow me to then listen onto the queue like so

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${activemq.queue.name}")
    public void receive(DomainObj obj)
```

Spring Integration Configuration

```
    @Configuration
    public class SpringIntegrationConfig {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringIntegrationConfig.class);

        @Value("${database.polling-interval.rate-in-milliseconds}")
        private Long pollingRateInMilliSeconds;

        @Value("${database.max-messages-per-poll}")
        private Long maxMessagesPerPoll;

        @Bean
        public MessageChannel helloWorldChannel() {
            return new DirectChannel();
        }

        @Bean
        public PollerMetadata poller(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(pollingRateInMilliSeconds);
            trigger.setFixedRate(true);

            MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource attributeSource = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
            attributeSource.setTransactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
            TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, attributeSource);

            PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
            poller.setTrigger(trigger);
            poller.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll);
            poller.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
            return  poller;
        }

        @Bean
        @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "helloWorldChannel", channel = "helloWorldChannel", poller = @Poller("poller"))
        public MessageSource<?> helloWorldMessageSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, "select * from item where type = 2");
            adapter.setUpdateSql("update item set type = 10 where id in (:id)");
            adapter.setRowMapper(new ItemRowMapper());
            adapter.setMaxRowsPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll.intValue()); 
            return adapter;
        }

        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "helloWorldChannel")
        public MessageHandler jsmOutboundAdapter(JmsTemplate template, Queue queue, MessageConverter converter) {
            template.setMessageConverter(converter);
            JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(template);
            handler.setDestination(queue);
            return handler;
        } 

    @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jsonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select statement to use the JDBC vendor syntax to only retrieve one record - e.g. `LIMIT 1`.

Then, remove the `setMaxRowsPerPoll()` (leave it to default at 0) and you will get the single result.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I just tried it out. It does get a single result, but the object still gets serialized to a json array. Is it possible to have the result serialized to a json object?

Comment: My apoligies; it's always a list; you can add a `@Transformer` to the flow `public Object transform(List<Object> list) { return list.get(0); }`.

Comment: Ah ok. That works. Thank you very much. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transformer public Object transform(List<Object> list) { return list.get(0); }` worked with the use of a SQL LIMIT. That's how you get it to return a json object, instead of an array.